# Unable to build 7z.dll

Tags: c++, dll, 7zip

I'm trying to build a debug version of 7z.dll with Visual Studio 2015.
I've downloaded 7z1900-src.7z and lzma1900.7z, extracted and merged the 2 archives and opened the project Format7z. After fixing an incompatible compile option the compilation ran through until the linker step.
When the linker get's invoked I get the following error message:

```
1>  Starting pass 1
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '.\Debug\\.obj'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(638,5): error MSB6006: "link.exe" exited with code 1181.
```

Does anybody has a hint where the ".obj" can come from?

Comment: That's an empty name.  It looks like maybe the project is substituting some variable that does not exist.

Comment: Is there a verbose mode or any option to find out which variable is empty?

Comment: @MartinBammer See [How to: View, Save, and Configure Build Log Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-view-save-and-configure-build-log-files?view=vs-2015).